# SwiftUI - Left squeeze views in a ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to loop through a list of 2-6 items. They are all Text() views for this example, and I want them to all squeeze to the left. This code below is as close as I have gotten

**Why?** I am simplifying the actual problem to make solving easier

```
HStack{
                                        
  ForEach(array, id: \.self) { pageItem in
     HStack{
      
       PageDataItemView(pageItem: pageItem)
       
      }.fixedSize()

    }                                 
   
    VStack(){
        Spacer()
      }                           
  }
 .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
 .frame(height: 40.0)
```

PageDataItemView for this example is just Text().

Anyway what I can't seem to solve is to make PageDataItemView's width based on the text content. In the code above they squeeze, but they all overlap each other, rather than taking their own space. Removing .fixedSize() above causes the items to fill the full width evenly.

In Android's XML I could just use "wrap_content" to produce this. While I understand this is not the ideal way to build UI here, it has to do with a complex client request.

Update:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
```

Seems to be causing my views to break as this is inside PageDataItemView. Even when geometry isn't even used at all. Once removed everything worked as expected, curious why this effects a view indirectly. Let me know if I should remove this question.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do or what your code is doing. By default, a Text() will size to smallest size to fit. Do you have a picture or something?

Comment: @nicksarno It sounds like you understand. I am wondering if because Text is nested in another view it doesn't work this way? When I swapped PageDataItemView for Text() it works exactly as expected. Maybe I am missing an obvious bug then in my PageDataItemView

Comment: There must be something else you added in PageDataItemView that is making it larger...

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I'll work this backwards and see if I can find my breaking point.

Comment: @nicksarno Okay so weird issue (bug?), if I replace PageDataItemView with Text() it works. If I remove all of PageDataItemView's content with "return Text()". It fills the max width. Edit: Removing GeometryReader {geometry in fixed it.. didn't realize that effected views..

Comment: Yea, GeometryReader will do that. It's not a bug, just how it works unfortunately.